# Remove data by Id

Tags: angular, typescript

Actually, I want to delete data from list. But I've got a litter problem with this code.

**Component Code**

```
removeSelectedRows(){
    console.log(this.selection.selected.map(item => item.userId))
    const selectedRowIds = this.selection.selected.map(item => item.userId);
       console.log(selectedRowIds)
      this.UserService.deleteUser(selectedRowIds).subscribe(res =>{
        this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter(data => data.userId !== selectedRowIds);
      }, err =>{
        console.error(err);  
      }, ()=>{
        // this.clearUserForm();
        this.loadUsers(this.pageIndex);
      });
  }
```

And the error come out from this part `this.UserService.deleteUser(selectedRowIds).subscribe(res =>{
            this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter(data => data.userId !== selectedRowIds)`.

`selectRowIds` error come out

> Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Comment: Looks like `selectedRowIds` is a *string[]* and you are trying to compare it with a *string*.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I've put like this `const selectedRowIds: string[] = this.selection.selected.map(item => item.agentId);` but it not working

Comment: That still wouldn't work as the error is coming in the `filter(...)`

Comment: Like  Nicholas K says, the problem is that you compare an array of strings to a single string.
Therefore, try changing string[] = this.selection.selected.map(item => item.agentId);to string[] = this.selection.selected.map(item => item.agentId)[0]

Comment: Can you give a proper answer?. Easy me to understand

Answer (score 0):

`selectedRowIds` is an array. So you cannot compare `string` with `array of strings`. Perhaps you can use [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
this.dataSource.data.filter(data => !selectedRowIds.includes(data.userId))
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Update**

This is only an assumption since I don't know the content of `deleteUser` method. The method of the service seems to expect a **single** ID of a user. Therefore you either need to iterate over the selected IDs or refactor the service method to make it accept an array of IDs. But be careful, if you iterate over the array and make separate calls for each user, and if it calls an API endpoint, it can cause undesired behavior.

```
selectedRowIds.forEach((selectedID) => {

    this.UserService.deleteUser(selectedID).subscribe(res =>{
    //                            ^^ Here's a single ID

        this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter(data => data.userId !== selectedID);
    //                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ filter by selectedID
      }, err =>{
        console.error(err);  
      }, ()=>{
        // this.clearUserForm();
        this.loadUsers(this.pageIndex);
      }
    );
});
```

But I do not recommend this way. It can cause multiple calls to API (if you use any)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But how about this part call service `this.UserService.deleteUser(selectedRowIds).subscribe(res =>{` I still got error with this `selectedRowIds`

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer and it has solve my problem

**Component Code**

```
selectedRow: any;

removeSelectedRows(){
    console.log(this.selectedRow.userId)
       this.UserService.deleteUser(this.selectedRow.userId).subscribe(res =>{
        this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter(data => data.userId!== this.selectedRow.userId);
      }, err =>{
        console.error(err);  
      }, ()=>{
        this.ngOnInit();
        this.loadUsers(this.pageIndex);
      });
  }
```